# Can't change DocumentBaseUrl in TinyMCE

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce

I'm using Rails 3.2.3, and when TinyMCE loads in production, I get four 404s:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://[my-domain]/[current-path]//langs/en.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://[my-domain]/[current-path]//plugins/fullscreen/editor_plugin.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://[my-domain]/[current-path]//themes/advanced/editor_template.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://[my-domain]/[current-path]//plugins/media/editor_plugin.js"
```

Maybe these files are called asynchronously from tiny_mce.js because they're not listed in my source. My js looks like this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    theme: "advanced",
    mode: "textareas",
    plugins: "fullscreen, media",
    height: 300,
    relative_urls :true,
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,fullscreen,spellchecker",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "styleselect,formatselect,imageListBox,media",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    editor_selector : "mceEditor",
    extended_valid_elements : "form[action|accept|accept-charset|enctype|method|name|onsubmit|id|name]",
    convert_urls : false,
    remove_script_host : false
});

function toggleTinyMCE(id) {
    if (!tinyMCE.get(id))
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, id);
    else
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, id);
}
```

All of my TinyMCE files are in the dir app/assets/javascripts/tiny_mce, so I have tried adding `document_base_url` and `base_url` to my init params, but no matter what I set them, when I inspect TinyMCE in firebug, I see that their values do not change to what I have entered.

I am aware that a Rails plugin by kete exists for tinyMCE, but [its README](https://github.com/kete/tiny_mce/) states that it is not recommended for Rails >= 3.1

Comment: The answer on this question helped a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325364/tinymce-loading-lang-plugins-theme-from-incorrect-directory

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help you, but you can give it a try. Here is the section about relative and absolute urls of the tinymce FAQ: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#Paths.2FURLs_are_incorrect.2C_I_want_absolute.2Frelative_URLs.3F

Comment: Thanks. I examined the page and played around with the params they described, but I didn't see anything that should make a difference, and I still was unable to change `documentBaseURL`.

Comment: sry, actually i do not have any other ideas

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to change document_base_url. You can add tinymce directly to the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/vendor/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

And the make shure all the file from tinymce is complied the assets pipline by adding to config/application.rb

```
config.assets.precompile << 'vendor/tiny_mce/*'
```

Comment: My problem isn't that `tiny_mce.js` doesn't load or that the support files don't exist but that tinymce is looking for the support files in the wrong place. `tiny_mce.js` is already loading correctly on the page; otherwise, the browser would never attempt to load the tinymce support files I mentioned above. So adding it (again) to the front end as you suggest makes no difference. What's more, it's already in the asset pipeline (under `app/assets/javascripts`), and putting it elsewhere, then manually adding it to the asset pipeline also makes no difference.